# wrong input file - Colour Scale Bar for one-band rasters

Tags: scale, color

I am now using the Colour Scale Bar for one-band rasters. I have saved my style as the .qml as shown in Fig. below.
[image]

And then I tried to input the .qml to Colour Scale Bar for one-band rasters. And the error occured as - wrong input file.

[image]

I also tried to use the current raster, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your qml file was created from a Vector Layer. They are in different format.

Comparing color codes in qml files from Vector and Raster, Raster uses Hex code and Vector uses RGBA. So even if you try manually copy and paste color information, it is difficult to transfer those information from Vector to Raster qmls.

If you really want to use the same color scale as vector layer, try `color picker` instead.

[image]

As to your issue with "Use current raster" option, there is no detailed information... but I suppose you may have seen an error message `No Raster Layer Selected! You must select a raster layer.`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am new to QGIS. I wanna create the colour scale bar for my colour filled map. And I search online, it is said this plugin works. May I know what do you mean by color picker? If it means I change the colour of current layer?

Comment: @mengyu Please find added image of `Change color` dialog, which you can call up by double-clicking on any color on your Raster `Singleband pseudo color` interpolation. There you see color picker - a spoit.

Comment: I am sorry but I only find the first three three options but no picker. I am using mac + QGIS version 2.18.7

Comment: My apologies. I did not know that difference between Win and Mac... The image posted came from QGIS 2.14 (I see it in 2.18, too) on Windows. Can you find a `Pick Color` option somewhere?

Comment: It is said that in their official website that 'In QGIS 2.18: Color picker is now embedded in layer style panel'. So if I choose a custom color, then the next step is also save the style as a .qml file as the input of the Colour Scale Bar for one-band rasters?

Comment: OK. And Yes to your next step...btw, are you, by any chance, trying to use this tool for your vector layer to make a legend?

Comment: I just tried this but it still doesn't work... No, I didn't use this. I just begun use this sotware for a week

Comment: Maybe you can add your current workflow (saving qml of your Raster layer) to your post.